# Audio,vedio and imagine insertion in html

Tags: html

How to get those audio and  video links to place in html code.when I share file to other devices and open it from there, why the image is not displaying in html and same goes with audio also.

Comment: Could you please explain your question better?

Answer (score 0):

exemple:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

its about absolute and relative paths...just see this link  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp